# how to display and where to display a pdf file by considering filePath in swift 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, swift3, webview

I am new to iOS development. In my project i am displaying a exerciseFilePath on tableview. 
the response is given below.

```
    "exerciseId" : 1,
    "exerciseName" : "Fitness Exercise",
    "exerciseFilePath" : "\/p\/pdf\/exercise_pdf\/fitness_exercise.pdf"
```

i need to display the pdf in another view on didSelectRowAtIndexpath.
i Dont know how to display the pdf and what are steps to be followed to display that pdf.
I hope you understand my problem. please help me how I can do this.

Comment: you can do it through `webView`

Comment: use `UIDocumentInteractionController` for show the PDF , for example see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177398/open-pdf-url-in-ios-8

Comment: another tutorial http://www.iostutorialjunction.com/2016/09/how-to-create-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-in-swift-language-ios-sdk.html

Comment: @Bhagyashree is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [QLPreviewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller)  or [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller)?

Now in your case you can do it by using `webView`:

```
let req = NSURLRequest(url: pdf) //pdf is your pdf path
let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:self.view.frame.size.width,height: self.view.frame.size.height-40)) //Adjust view area here
webView.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)
self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

---

*Some tutorials:*

[QLPreviewController example](https://www.appcoda.com/quick-look-framework/)

[UIDocumentInteractionController example](https://ayeohyes.wordpress.com/tag/uidocumentinteractioncontroller/)