# iOS Swift - How to show a pdf file, which is inside local storage in the adobe reader

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, pdf

I am trying to create an application where a the pdf is getting saved in the local storage and I want that pdf to be opened in Adobe Reader.

Also, I don't want to open the pdf inside any web view. Infact, I want pdf to be opened in Adobe Reader.

I have searched a lot but had no success, all the examples were for opening pdf inside web view.

Below is my code:

```
@IBAction func savePDF(_ sender: Any) {
        let pdfData = Data(base64Encoded: FilePDF, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
        let array = pdfData?.withUnsafeBytes
        {
            [UInt8](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: (pdfData?.count)!))
        }
        let data = NSData(bytes: array, length: (array?.count)!);
        let tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
     //   data.write(toFile: tmpDir.appending("HandyHR_File_YEAR.pdf"), atomically: true)
         print(array!)
        print(data)
        print(tmpDir)
        data.write(toFile: tmpDir.appending("HandyHR_File_YEAR.pdf"), atomically: true)

   }
```

The variable `tmpDir` stores the path for the pdf in the local storage.

Any help would b appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have to show `UIDocumentInteractionController` and let the user choose

Comment: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229512/how-to-display-and-where-to-display-a-pdf-file-by-considering-filepath-in-swift/45229615#45229615).

Comment: @Tj3n  What if I don't want the user to view the file in the web view. Yes I can give user the options if he want to to open the file pdf viewer other than Adobe. But I am only getting the examples for the web view.

Comment: Why don't you use QLPreviewController or UIDocumentInteractionController? Check the previous comment of mine for reference.

Comment: @AnuragSharma  I already mentioned above the I don't want to use the Web View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller) to display the file:

Instance variable containing the controller:

```
fileprivate lazy var docInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController = {
    return UIDocumentInteractionController()
}()
```

Presenting the preview:

```
let tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
let fileName = "HandyHR_File_YEAR.pdf"

// Save file    

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: tmpDir).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
docInteractionController.url = url
docInteractionController.delegate = self

if docInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true) {
    // Successfully displayed
} else {
    // Couldn't display
}
```

You would also implement the delegate to specify the view controller which presents the preview:

```
extension YourViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        // I tend to use 'navigationController ?? self' here but depends on implementation
        return self 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use QuickLook framework for show pdf, word, etc. file. 
[link](https://www.appcoda.com/quick-look-framework/) here